# Добавление нового пользователя через yast

Tags: opensuse, linux, gnome

Подскажите, как добавить пользователя? Сейчас, когда добавляю нового пользователя, через yast2 и ставлю ему автоматический вход в систему (openSuse 12. 1 Gnome 3. 2) то при входе, все рушится и невозможно войти, а мне надо добавить user и запретить ему открывать папку другого пользователя и читать второй жесткий диск. Помогите добавить и настроить пользователя, система openSuse 12. 1 Gnome 3. 2

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через команду useradd.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, система не может создать папку пользователя. Посмотрите `ls /home/` - должна быть папка с именем пользователя, да и имена пользователей должны быть латинскими буквами.